# Make image fit in slideshow container

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I am making a simple slideshow that will go on a website I am making and the images I use/need are larger than the div itself!

They dont overflow as I used `overflow: hidden`, however they dont shrink to fit the container!

I tried adding things like `max-width: 100%` and things like that but none of it works :(

Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/V7Cv9/

Comment: Try not to use local images in jsFiddles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the image is contained by the sub div, apply your 240px height to the sub div and then make the img have 100% height

```
.slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.slideshow > div > img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5NgN/

Comment: This works! But some of my images still dont really fit the container: http://i.imgur.com/zoAPkhk.png

Comment: actually! I fixed that by using width: 100%; for the img also! Thanks for the help!